# How to remove all characters after first instance of punctuation/blank space?

Tags: python-3.x

I have short strings (tweets) in which I must extract all instances of mentions from the text and return a list of these instances including repeats.

> > > extract_mentions('.@AndreaTantaros-supersleuth! You are a true journalistic professional. Keep up the great work! #MakeAmericaGreatAgain')
> > >       [AndreaTantaros]

How do I make it so that I remove all text after the first instance of punctuation after '@'? (In this case it would be '-') Note, punctuation can be varied. Please no use of regex.

I have used the following:

```
tweet_list = tweet.split()
    mention_list = []
    for word in tweet_list:
        if '@' in word:
            x = word.index('@')
            y = word[x+1:len(word)]
            if y.isalnum() == False:
                y = word[x+1:-1]
                mention_list.append(y)
            else:                
                mention_list.append(y)
    return mention_list
```

This would only work for instances with one extra character

Comment: So what have you tried, and why does it not work as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.punctuation` module to get all punctuation chars.

Remove the first characters while they are punctuation (else the answer would be empty string all the time). Then find the first punctuation char.

This uses 2 loops with opposite conditions and a `set` for better speed.

```
z =".@AndreaTantaros-supersleuth! You are a true journalistic professional. Keep up the great work! #MakeAmericaGreatAgain') [AndreaTantaros]"

import string

# skip leading punctuation: find position of first non-punctuation

spun=set(string.punctuation)  # faster if searched from a set

start_pos = 0
while z[start_pos] in spun:
    start_pos+=1

end_pos = start_pos
while z[end_pos] not in spun:
    end_pos+=1

print(z[start_pos:end_pos])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def extract_mentions(s, delimeters = string.punctuation + string.whitespace):
  mentions = []
  begin = s.find('@')
  while begin >= 0:
    end = begin + 1
    while end < len(s) and s[end] not in delimeters:
      end += 1
    mentions.append(s[begin+1:end])
    begin = s.find('@', end)
  return mentions


>>> print(extract_mentions('.@AndreaTantaros-supersleuth! You are a true journalistic professional. Keep up the great work! #MakeAmericaGreatAgain'))
['AndreaTantaros']
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use regexp to match and extract part of the text.

Comment: From OP: *Please no use of regex.*

Comment: Sorry. Did not read that. Anyway, regexps are most fastest and overall suitable way for this task.